# Prove that the set $[0,1)$ is a closed set in the half-open interval topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Prove that the set $[0,1)$ is a closed set in the half-open interval topology of **R**.

I know that I need to show that the complement of this set is open in order to show that this set is closed.

The complement of the set is $(-\infty, 0) \cup [1, \infty)$.  However, based on my definition of a half open topology I do not see how this is open?

My definition of a half-open topology is "The collection of *H* of all subsets *U* of **R** such that either $ U = \emptyset $ or for each $ x \in U$ there is an interval of the form $[a,b)$ for which $ x \in$ $[a,b)$ $\subseteq U $ is a topology for **R**.

My area I have the issue with is from 0 to 1. Am I overthinking this? If I pick any point to the left of O can I simply write the interval to be $[-5, 0)$ and just not include any numbers between zero and 1. What about 0?

Comment: I think you mean "Prove that the set $[0,1)$ is a closed **set** *in the* half-open interval topology of $\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: That is what I meant. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the right way.

Yes, pick any $x \in (-\infty,0) \cup [1,\infty)$. If $x \in (-\infty,0)$ then $x$ **IS LESS THAN** zero! So $[x,0)$ will work. :)

For $x \in [1,\infty)$ just use something like $[1,x+1)$.

I hope this helps!